Linear Programming Problem using lpSolveAPI
I am trying to create a linear programming model that will find the optimal mix of bonds to sell that maximizes book yield, exceed a certain market value, do not fall below a certain gain/loss amount, and are limited to the maximum amount that is actually owned of the bond.
Here is a sample of data from a bond portfolio that I am working with:
min   max     market_value    gain_loss    book_yield
0    0.192    5793070.000    -2096660.217   1.564
0    0.332    10013973.531   -257093.942    5.304
0    0.357    10741519.024   -3612018.833   1.614
0    0.118    3552909.914    -127308.087    4.218
0   0.00006   1834.918       -4.967         5.023

Here is my current code:
library(lpSolve)
library(lpSolveAPI)
library(readxl)

setwd(directory)


bond_data2 <- read_xlsx("Transaction Model2.xlsx")
View(bond_data2)

gain_loss2 <- bond_data2$`Gain/Loss`
market_value2 <- bond_data2$`Market Value`
book_yield2 <- bond_data2$`Book Yield`
max_owned2 <- bond_data2$Max
 
lp_model2 <- make.lp(0, ncol=length(max_owned2))  

set.objfn(lp_model2, book_yield2)

for (i in seq_along(max_owned2)) { 
  set.bounds(lp_model2, columns = i, upper = max_owned2[i], lower = 0) 
}

add.constraint(lp_model2, c(market_value2), ">=", 15000000)

add.constraint(lp_model2, c(gain_loss2), ">=", -2000000) 

solve(lp_model2) 
 
solution <- get.variables(lp_model2) 
solution
 
print(get.objective(lp_model2))

print(get.constraints(lp_model2))

bonds_to_sell2 <- bond_data2[solution > 0, ]
print(bonds_to_sell2$CUSIP)

print.lpExtPtr(lp_model2)

Here are the results I receive:
>solution
[1] 6.952180e-310 3.799365e-321  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00

Which clearly are unfeasible and make no sense, however, when I print the properties of the mode, they all look how I want them to:
>C1                    C2                    C3                    C4                    C5  
           
>Minimize                 1.564                 5.304                 1.614                 4.218                 5.023     
        
>R1                     5793070       10013973.530993      10741519.024      3552909.91400      1834.918000  >=  1.5e+07

>R2           -2096660.21700      -257093.94199     -3612018.83300     -127308.087000                -4.967  >=   -2e+06

>Kind                       Std                   Std                   Std                   Std                   Std 
            
>Type                      Real                  Real                  Real                  Real                  Real 
            
>Upper        0.192439652079616     0.332653598565203     0.356821889565486     0.118023905756426  6.09540332698593e-05   
          
>Lower                        0                     0                     0                     0                     0          

To simplify:
What is the best mix of bonds to sell that:

Minimize book yield
do not exceed a 2,000,000 loss
Provide 15,000,000 in market value.
maximum amount sold does not exceed what is owned (found in the max column which is that bonds ratio of the total sum of the market values)

Any help would be much appreciated.

The market value minimum of 15M is infeasible. The highest this can go given your other constraints is 8.7M.

In fact, the problem is trivial: for the provided input, the solution is to take the maximum for each bond amount (disregarding the market value constraint).

As in the comments, the problem is infeasible. Either:

Add more bond data rows, or
Dramatically increase the bond maxima, or
Dramatically decrease the $15M market value minimum.

Demonstrating in Python,
import io
import pandas as pd
import pulp

with io.StringIO(
'''
min  max  market_value    gain_loss     book_yield
0    1    5793070.000    -2096660.217   1.564
0    1    10013973.531   -257093.942    5.304
0    1    10741519.024   -3612018.833   1.614
0    1    3552909.914    -127308.087    4.218
0    1    1834.918       -4.967         5.023
''') as f:
    bond_data2 = pd.read_fwf(f)

bond_data2['bonds'] = pulp.LpVariable.matrix(name='bonds', indices=bond_data2.index)
for idx, row in bond_data2.iterrows():
    row['bonds'].bounds(low=row['min'], up=row['max'])

book_yield = pulp.lpDot(bond_data2['book_yield'], bond_data2['bonds'])
market_value = pulp.lpDot(bond_data2['market_value'], bond_data2['bonds'])
gain = pulp.lpDot(bond_data2['gain_loss'], bond_data2['bonds'])
lp_model2 = pulp.LpProblem(name='bond_portfolio', sense=pulp.LpMaximize)
lp_model2.setObjective(book_yield)
lp_model2.addConstraint(name='min_market_value', constraint=market_value >= 15e6)
lp_model2.addConstraint(name='min_gain', constraint=gain >= -2e6)
lp_model2.solve()
assert lp_model2.status == pulp.LpStatusOptimal

bond_data2 = bond_data2.map(pulp.value)
print(bond_data2)
print(f'  Book yield: {book_yield.value():.3f}')
print(f'Market value: ${market_value.value():,.0f}')
print(f'        Gain: ${gain.value():,.0f}')

   min  max  market_value    gain_loss  book_yield     bonds
0    0    1  5.793070e+06 -2096660.217       1.564  0.770555
1    0    1  1.001397e+07  -257093.942       5.304  1.000000
2    0    1  1.074152e+07 -3612018.833       1.614  0.000000
3    0    1  3.552910e+06  -127308.087       4.218  1.000000
4    0    1  1.834918e+03       -4.967       5.023  1.000000
  Book yield: 15.750
Market value: $18,032,600
        Gain: $-2,000,000

